# Cordova and startResolutionForResult VS. startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, cordova, google-play-services

I am making a Cordova plugin for Google Play. At the moment I've "corrupted" the plugin by modifying my CordovaActivity function manually. I need to put all the code inside of the plugin file, not split it between the CordovaActivity and the plugin file.

To do this, I need to transfer callbacks to `onActivityResult` initiated via `startResolutionForResult` into a plugin-specific function. As a comparison, I believe `startActivityForResult` does have this mechanism, but I cannot find anything similar for `startResolutionForResult`.

Can anyone think of a mechanism to do this?

Here is my CordovaActivity code and my plugin code.

CordovaActivity:

```
package com.flyingsoft.safari.jigsaw.free;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

import android.util.Log;

import android.content.Intent;

import com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayservices.GooglePlayServices;

public class MyGame extends CordovaActivity {

 private static final String LOGTAG = "MyGame";

 public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
  Log.w (LOGTAG, "onActivityResult");
  if (!GooglePlayServices.mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) GooglePlayServices.mGoogleApiClient.connect ();
 }

 @Override public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
  super.init ();
  super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
 }
}
```

```
Plugin:

package com.flyingsoftgames.googleplayservices;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Players;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Account;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult.Status;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.util.Log;

public class GooglePlayServices extends CordovaPlugin implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

 private static final String LOGTAG = "GooglePlayServices";
 private static final int REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED = 55664;

 public CordovaInterface       cordova            = null;
 public CordovaWebView         webView            = null;
 public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient   = null;
 public CallbackContext        tryConnectCallback = null;
 public String                 accessToken        = "";

 @Override public void initialize (CordovaInterface initCordova, CordovaWebView initWebView) {
  cordova  = initCordova;
  webView  = initWebView;
  super.initialize (cordova, webView);
 }

 @Override public void onConnectionFailed (ConnectionResult result) {
  if (!result.hasResolution()) {Log.w (LOGTAG, "Error: no resolution. Google Play Services connection failed."); return;}
  try {
   result.startResolutionForResult (cordova.getActivity(), result.getErrorCode());
  } catch (SendIntentException e) {
   // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
   mGoogleApiClient.connect ();
  }
 }

 @Override public void onConnected (Bundle connectionHint) {
  String mAccountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
  new RetrieveTokenTask().execute (mAccountName);
  Games.setViewForPopups (mGoogleApiClient, webView);
 }

 public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
  if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) mGoogleApiClient.connect ();
 }

 @Override public void onConnectionSuspended (int cause) {
  mGoogleApiClient.connect ();
 }

 public boolean execute (String action, JSONArray inputs, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
  if        ("getPlayerId".equals(action)) {
   String playerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId (mGoogleApiClient);
   callbackContext.sendPluginResult (new PluginResult (PluginResult.Status.OK, playerId));
  } else if ("tryConnect".equals(action)) {
   tryConnect (callbackContext);
  } else if ("getAccessToken".equals(action)) {
   callbackContext.sendPluginResult (new PluginResult (PluginResult.Status.OK, accessToken));
  }
  return true;
 }

 // tryConnect runs the callback with a value of false if Google Play Services isn't available.
 public void tryConnect (CallbackContext callbackContext) {
  boolean isGpsAvailable = (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(cordova.getActivity()) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS);
  if (!isGpsAvailable) {
   callbackContext.sendPluginResult (new PluginResult (PluginResult.Status.OK, false));
   return;
  }
  tryConnectCallback = callbackContext;
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder (cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext())
   .addConnectionCallbacks (this)
   .addOnConnectionFailedListener (this)
   .addApi (Games.API)
   .addScope (Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
   .addApi(Plus.API)
   .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
   .build ();
  mGoogleApiClient.connect ();
 }


 private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override protected String doInBackground (String... params) {
   String accountName = params[0];
   String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PROFILE + " " + "email";
   Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Log.e (LOGTAG, "RetrieveTokenTask");
   try {
    accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken (context, accountName, scope);
    GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken (context, accessToken);
    accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken (context, accountName, scope);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e (LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
   } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
    cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult (e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
   } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
    Log.e (LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
   }
   return accessToken;
  }

  @Override protected void onPostExecute (String newAccessToken) {
   super.onPostExecute (newAccessToken);
   accessToken = newAccessToken;   
   if (tryConnectCallback != null) {
    String playerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId (mGoogleApiClient);
    tryConnectCallback.sendPluginResult (new PluginResult (PluginResult.Status.OK, playerId));
    tryConnectCallback = null;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this work? Have you found a solution to this issue? I have checked your Github account ant seems like you did not (the code is exactly the same as here). So I was wondering if you fixed the issue somehow... much appreciated...

Comment: I did not find a solution that didn't involve changing the activity file. If all you need is an authentication method you can use just Google (to get the token only) instead of Google+: https://github.com/agamemnus/Cordova-Google-Play-Token

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a solution for that.

In the initialize method of your class that extends the CordovaPlugin one just call:

```
cordova.setActivityResultCallback(this);
```

and then implement the method:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

as you would do normally on Android.

Comment: I actually have this in my Cordova-Google-Play-Token code, but it's been a while and it is all a bit of a mess so I forgot about that part! I will try to modify my Google Play Services code with it and see how it goes.

Comment: I didn't work on it, but they're changing/deprecating Google Play Services API or something anyway... I think the API is changing way too rapidly for anything like https://github.com/agamemnus/googleplayservices to be maintained well (by me, anyway). Do you want me to try to change it?

Comment: Naaa, just wondering. I also agree that at this speed is quite difficult to maintain anything as  side projects...